# Open full screen an image with multitouch in WPF

Tags: wpf

I'm developing a multitouch application. There is one way to open the image in fullscreen mode when i do the pinchzoom?

The code is this:

```
    <Window x:Class="TouchRect.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TouchRect" 
    Title="MainWindow" Height="700" Width="1000">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="189*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="472*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <!--<local:RulerCanvas x:Name="canvas"  >-->

        <Image x:Name="image3" Width="74" Height="49" IsManipulationEnabled="True" Source="flower3.jpg" Margin="446,-268,458,408">
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <MatrixTransform Matrix="2.41806325085411,0,0,2.41806325085411,280.737615796121,292.420001677231" />
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>
        <Image x:Name="image2" Width="74" Height="49" IsManipulationEnabled="True" Source="flower2.jpg" Margin="110,-266,794,406" Stretch="Fill" >
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <MatrixTransform  Matrix="2.41806325085411,0,0,2.41806325085411,280.737615796121,292.420001677231"/>
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>
        <Image x:Name="image" Width="74" Height="49" IsManipulationEnabled="True" Source="flower.jpg" Stretch=" fill" Margin="-248,-271,1152,411">
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <MatrixTransform Matrix="2.41806325085411,0,0,2.41806325085411,280.737615796121,292.420001677231" />
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>
    <MediaElement x:Name="media" Source="C:\Users\Public\Videos\Sample Videos\Wildlife.wmv" Canvas.Left="183" Canvas.Top="151" LoadedBehavior="Manual" IsManipulationEnabled="True" Margin="37,18,38,38" Grid.Row="1" />
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="100,86,0,0" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="217" />
    <!--</local:RulerCanvas>-->

</Grid>
```

I'm using this class in .cs

Where i have to add that code?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;

namespace TouchRect
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            media.Volume = 100;
            media.Play();
            this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainWindow_Loaded);

        }

        void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            canvas.ManipulationStarting += new EventHandler<ManipulationStartingEventArgs>(image_ManipulationStarting);
            canvas.ManipulationDelta += new EventHandler<ManipulationDeltaEventArgs>(image_ManipulationDelta);
             // inertia 
            canvas.ManipulationInertiaStarting += new EventHandler<ManipulationInertiaStartingEventArgs>(canvas_ManipulationInertiaStarting);


        }


void canvas_ManipulationInertiaStarting(object sender, ManipulationInertiaStartingEventArgs e)
{                
        // Decrease the velocity of the Rectangle's movement by 
        // 10 inches per second every second.
        // (10 inches * 96 DIPS per inch / 1000ms^2)
        e.TranslationBehavior = new InertiaTranslationBehavior()
        {
            InitialVelocity = e.InitialVelocities.LinearVelocity,
            DesiredDeceleration = 10.0 * 96.0 / (1000.0 * 1000.0)
        };

        // Decrease the velocity of the Rectangle's resizing by 
        // 0.1 inches per second every second.
        // (0.1 inches * 96 DIPS per inch / (1000ms^2)
        e.ExpansionBehavior = new InertiaExpansionBehavior()
        {
            InitialVelocity = e.InitialVelocities.ExpansionVelocity,
            DesiredDeceleration = 0.1 * 96 / 1000.0 * 1000.0
        };

        // Decrease the velocity of the Rectangle's rotation rate by 
        // 2 rotations per second every second.
        // (2 * 360 degrees / (1000ms^2)
        e.RotationBehavior = new InertiaRotationBehavior()
        {
            InitialVelocity = e.InitialVelocities.AngularVelocity,
            DesiredDeceleration = 720 / (1000.0 * 1000.0)
        };
        e.Handled = true;                  
}

UIElement last;    


void image_ManipulationStarting(object sender, ManipulationStartingEventArgs e)
{
    // lazy hack not in the blog post.. 
    var uie = e.OriginalSource as UIElement;    
    if (uie != null)
    {
        if (last != null) Canvas.SetZIndex(last, 0); 
        Canvas.SetZIndex(uie, 2);
        last = uie; 
    } 

    //canvas is the parent of the image starting the manipulation;
    //Container does not have to be parent, but that is the most common scenario
    e.ManipulationContainer = canvas;
    e.Handled = true; 
    // you could set the mode here too 
    // e.Mode = ManipulationModes.All;             
}

void image_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
{
    //this just gets the source. 
    // I cast it to FE because I wanted to use ActualWidth for Center. You could try RenderSize as alternate
    var element = e.Source as FrameworkElement; 
    if ( element != null ) 
    { 
        //e.DeltaManipulation has the changes 
        // Scale is a delta multiplier; 1.0 is last size,  (so 1.1 == scale 10%, 0.8 = shrink 20%) 
        // Rotate = Rotation, in degrees
        // Pan = Translation, == Translate offset, in Device Independent Pixels 

        var deltaManipulation = e.DeltaManipulation; 
        var matrix  = ((MatrixTransform)element.RenderTransform).Matrix;            
        // find the old center; arguaby this could be cached 
        Point center =  new Point ( element.ActualWidth/2, element.ActualHeight/2) ;
        // transform it to take into account transforms from previous manipulations 
        center = matrix.Transform(center); 
        //this will be a Zoom. 
        matrix.ScaleAt(deltaManipulation.Scale.X, deltaManipulation.Scale.Y, center.X, center.Y); 
        // Rotation 
        matrix.RotateAt(e.DeltaManipulation.Rotation, center.X, center.Y);             
        //Translation (pan) 
        matrix.Translate(e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.X, e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.Y);

        ((MatrixTransform)element.RenderTransform).Matrix = matrix; 

        e.Handled = true;

        // We are only checking boundaries during inertia 
        // in real world, we would check all the time 
        if (e.IsInertial)
        {
            Rect containingRect = new Rect(((FrameworkElement)e.ManipulationContainer).RenderSize);

            Rect shapeBounds = element.RenderTransform.TransformBounds(new Rect(element.RenderSize));

            // Check if the element is completely in the window.
            // If it is not and intertia is occuring, stop the manipulation.
            if (e.IsInertial && !containingRect.Contains(shapeBounds))
            {
                //Report that we have gone over our boundary 
                e.ReportBoundaryFeedback(e.DeltaManipulation); 
                // comment out this line to see the Window 'shake' or 'bounce' 
                // similar to Win32 Windows when they reach a boundary; this comes for free in .NET 4                
                e.Complete();
            }

        }          
    }
}


    }
```

Comment: If you need to post clarification that is too big to fit in a comment, it should just be included in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do that with code behind. Do these steps:

```
this.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
this.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
this.Topmost = true;
this.Top = 0;
this.Left = 0;
```

The seemingly useless first line is actually workaround to weird behavior of WPF window (where the window being maximized will not cover task bar if it is already maximized).

And as for the multitouch, [here](http://www.wpftutorial.net/Multitouch2.html) is tutorial.